# google plus app doesn't work well when integrate with iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, google-plus

i am working on iOS app that has Facebook and google plus login to start the app. my Facebook app works fine. but my google app create a problem.there are many issues with it.
1. google plus app don't return back to my app after successful login even with correct bundle id and url scheme both in project and api console.

After reset the iOS simulator due to some reasons the following problem occur:-

2. on successful login the app relaunches and if then **i press sign in button it do authentication as i see in my project output console but without showing any login sheet and without asking for permissions.**
   (above 2 steps happened for the first time launching after resting the simulator)
   and for the second time launching the app on simulator the bold text of step 2 happen.

I KNOW THIS IS VERY COMPLICATED BUT become headache of mine.so please help me on this.
the 2nd step occur only after resting the simulator. for your knowledge i am using iOS 7 and Xcode 5.1 and also plain view controllers. one more thing what i have noticed that google plus app -(void) signOut method does not called in either case and nor the disconnect method(used one method at a time).
thank you in advance.